# Null checking extension method

Tags: c#, linq, resharper, null-check

So, I'm doing a lot of database work in an application - and there are several possible return values of my caching system. It can return null, it can return a default (type) or it can return an invalid object (by invalid object, I mean one with incorrect properties / values). I want to create an extension method to make all those checks for me, like so:

```
    public static bool Valid<T> (this T obj) where T: class
    {
        if (obj == null) 
            return false;
        else if (obj == default(T))
            return false;
        //Other class checks here
        else 
            return true;
    }
```

The problem is, my compiler is telling me that `if (obj == default(T))` will always be false.

Why is that?

Comment: Is it giving you a compiler error or warning. I'm getting neither. it compiles fine.

Comment: @GregB. It's probably `resharper` that gives him a hint...

Comment: @GregB yes, I have resharper.

Comment: @caesay - I don't understand the problem.  The default value for a reference to a class is null.  The default value of a reference to an Object is also going to be null.  It sounds like you don't understand the synax of your own code.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'll admit, it was a total misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you have a "class" constraint (`where T: class`), `default(T)` is **always** equal to null.  You already have a check for that in the original if statement, so the second case (`obj == default(T)`) could never be true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are constraining it to class because you want to or because you feel you have to.  If it's the latter, here is a way to do default value checking on complex and simple types:

```
public static bool Valid<T> (this T obj)
{
    return !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj, default(T));
}
```

If your choice to constrain it to class only was intentional or for a business case, feel free to ignore this suggestion.  Another thing this may not account for is boxing of simple types (although I usually use nullable simple types these days, which this code does work for).

Answer (score 0):

The first decision you need to make is: Can *T* be a value type like *int*?
If so you can remove

```
 where T: class
```

and

```
if (obj == null) return false;
else
```

If *T* is always a reference type you can remove

```
if (obj == null) return false;
```